# How to make a sequences from a range

Tags: r

I am trying to make a sequences from a range from the output of range.

```
> range(wines$quality)
 [1] 3 8
> seq(3, 8)
 [1] 3 4 5 6 7 8
> seq(range(wines$quality))
 [1] 1 2
```

but I am trying to get put the output of range 3, 8 into seq to get the list of 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8 why is giving me a list with 1 2? How do a make it behave as I want?

Comment: If you pass a vector or data.frame x as one argument to seq it will create a sequence 1:length(x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option:

```
do.call(seq, as.list(range(wines$quality)))
# [1] 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

You problem right now is you are passing a two element vector as one argument, when `seq` expects two one element arguments in order for it to do what you want.

`do.call` calls `seq` with each of the items in `as.list...` as an argument.

Comment: Nice I like this the best as a one liner. +1

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a fancier way to do it but why not just:

```
x <- range(wine$quality)
seq(x[1], x[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Some possible solutions, though the `eval` `parse` is more fooling around:

```
set.seed(10)
x <- rpois(20, 10)

y <- range(x); y[1]:y[2]
seq(y[1], y[2])
eval(parse(text = paste(range(x), collapse=":")))

## > y <- range(x); y[1]:y[2]
##  [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

## > seq(y[1], y[2])
##  [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

## > eval(parse(text = paste(range(x), collapse=":")))
##  [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```